# react-native on press button show touch ID view (iOS)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm making react-native app made with 'create-react-native-app' and expo SDK, I want to make it show touch ID view on press button. I know that expo client comes with all native stuff like: touch ID , contacts. But when I implement build in functions and test it by pressing button on my phone it shows an error.

**This is an error that I get:**

[image]

**Here is part of code that I am working with**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    StatusBar,
    TextInput,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

import Expo from 'expo';

    class LoginButton extends Component {
    render() {
        if(Expo.Fingerprint.hasHardwareAsync()) {
            return (
                <Button onPress={Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync()} title="Sign In" color="#2187BA" backgroundColor=""/>
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onPress={()=>Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync();}
```

Comment: Just don't forget to mark it as an answer if it does resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'll update this since I arrived here looking for another answer - "FingerPrint" has been replaced by "LocalAuthentication", so instead of

```
Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync()
```

You will want

```
Expo.LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it is better not create new functions with every render.

```
onPress={Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync}
```